# Using Circe custom codec to decode json to a list of a case class

Tags: json, scala, decode, circe

I am trying to use Circe's custom codecs to decode json to a List of a trait `Feature` which is broken down into two case classes:

```scala
trait Feature {
  def name: String
  def index: Int
  def frequency: Int
}

case class NumericFeature(name, index, frequency) extends Feature
case class SetFeature(name, index, set, frequency) extends Feature
```

from the json shown here:

```
[
 {
   "name" : "ElectionReturns_G16CountyTurnoutAllRegisteredVoters",
   "index" : 1770,
   "frequency" : 2992
 },
{
   "name" : "CommercialDataLL_Home_Owner_Or_Renter",
   "index" : 1112,
   "set" : [
     "Likely Homeowner",
     "",
     "Likely Renter",
    ],
   "frequency" : 2537
},
   .
   .
   .
   .
]
```

This is the code that works for a single instance of a case class aka:

```
{
   "name" : "ElectionReturns_G16CountyTurnoutAllRegisteredVoters",
   "index" : 1770,
   "frequency" : 2992
 }
```

```scala
import io.circe.Json
import io.circe._
import io.circe.parser._

implicit val decoder: Decoder[Feature] = new Decoder[Feature] {
      final def apply(h: HCursor): Decoder.Result[Feature] = for {

          name <- h.get[String]("name")
          index <- h.get[Int]("index")
          set <- h.getOrElse[Set[String]]("set")(Set[String]())
          frequency <- h.get[Int]("frequency")
          feature: Feature = set match {
            case s if s.isEmpty => new NumericFeature(name, index, frequency)
            case _ => new SetFeature(name, index, set, frequency)
          }
        } yield feature
     }

val decoded = decoder.decodeJson(parse(json).getOrElse(Json.Null))
```

How can I adapt this to output a list? I have tried just changing the output type of the decoder to `List[Feature]` because I thought the for loop would yield a list, but this isn't the case.

Here is my attempt at a Decoder returning a Decoder[List[Feature]]:

```
implicit val decoder: Decoder[List[Feature]] = new Decoder[List[Feature]] {
      final def apply(h: HCursor): Decoder.Result[List[Feature]]= {

        val feature = for {

          name <- h.get[String]("name")
          index <- h.get[Int]("index")
          set <- h.getOrElse[Set[String]]("set")(Set[String]())
          frequency <- h.get[Int]("frequency")
          feature: Feature = set match {
            case s if s.isEmpty => new NumericFeature(name, index, frequency)
            case _ => new SetFeature(name, index, set, frequency)
          }
        } yield feature
        feature.asInstanceOf[Decoder.Result[List[Feature]]]
      }
    }
val decoded = decoder.decodeJson(parse(json).getOrElse(Json.Null))
```

Comment: So you don't have the wrapping `[` and `]` around the JSON objects?

Comment: If you have a `Decoder[Feature]`, circe will automatically provide a `Decoder[List[Feature]]`—this is generally the way type classes work in Scala (and other languages).

Comment: @Travis Brown - This doesn't seem to be the case when I have been testing, perhaps the way I am using it is wrong? I am using `decoder.decodeJson(parse(json).getOrElse(Json.Null))` to decode my json.

Comment: @RileyWhite I'll try to take a look if you provide a complete example.

Comment: @TravisBrown Sure, what else do you need exactly, that is almost all the code I am using, thanks.

Comment: I can't copy and paste what you have now, since there are missing definitions, and you don't actually show anywhere you're trying to decode a `List[Feature]`.

Comment: Ok, I have updated my answer, which includes where I try to use the decoder now.

Comment: @RileyWhite You shouldn't ever need to write a `Decoder[List[X]]`—you provide an implicit `Decoder[X]`, and then use something like `io.circe.parser.decode[List[X]](myJson)`.

Comment: Hi @RileyWhite.  I had a similar challenge as you and I _think_ I finally figured it out.  I have created a gist that tries to show how I went about it.

https://gist.github.com/dholtz/5065d5ea77f345589ad607abceb0ff75

The thing that I missed were the docs around encoding/decoding ADT's
https://circe.github.io/circe/codecs/adt.html

Answer (score 1):

Just use `io.circe.parser.decode` given you have the `Decoder[Feature]` in scope:

```
io.circe.parser.decode[Seq[Feature]](json)
```

You don't have to provide a `Decoder[Seq[Feature]]`.

Comment: Sorry I actually do have the wrapping `[]` in my JSON, I have updated my post. Also, I can't use the decode function because I need to handle two different cases.

Comment: I edited my answer, that should just work. Make sure not to define any `Decoder[Seq[Feature]]`, they are provided by circe.

Answer (score -1):

try to use custom decoder. This approach works for me:

```
import cats.Show
import cats.implicits._
import io.circe.Decoder

object Feature {
  implicit val featureDecoder: Decoder[Feature] = List[Decoder[Feature]](
    Decoder[NumericFeature].widen,
    Decoder[SetFeature].widen
  ).reduceLeft(_ or _)
}
```

Comment: Someone vote with - without explanation.
It is exactly what @Riley White asked. He needs to handle two different cases in one decoder